# Filter query who contains ICollection property via LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 models: ApplicationUser and TaskModel

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public virtual ICollection<TaskModel> Tasks { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

and

```
public class TaskModel
{
     public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Managers { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

I want select from database only that record who contains some AplicationUser object in Managers.
Than I tried using LINQ

```
ApplicationUser currentUser = "SomeObject";
var taskModels = db.Tasks.Where(t => t.Managers.Contains(currentUser)).Include(t => t.Autor);
```

But that generated error in Where clause. The error message says "Unable to create a constant "TaskToDo.Models.ApplicationUser" type. In this context it supports only primitive types, and enumeration types."
I get what I need via next code

```
var allTasks = db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Autor).ToList();
List<TaskModel> filterTasks = new List<TaskModel>();
foreach (var task in allTasks)
{
   if (task.Managers.Contains(currentUser))
       filterTasks.Add(task);
}
return View(filterTasks);
```

But I'd like to know how it solve via LINQ syntax

Comment: add `.ToList();` end of your linq like  `db.Tasks.Where(t => t.Managers.Contains(currentUser)).Include(t => t.Autor).ToList();`

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use `contains` in LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `Any` method where you can specify a column to compare, for sample:

```
var taskModels = db.Tasks
                   .Where(t => t.Managers.Any(m => m.Id == currentUser.Id))
                   .Include(t => t.Autor) 
                   .ToList();
```

Don't forget to call a method to execute this statement, such as `ToList()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Contains` with your `ApplicationUser` instance because the query is executed by [LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [LINQ to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using the Entity Framework) and obviously your database does not know your `ApplicationUser` class.

Your second approach is working because after calling `ToList()` the remaining code is executed by [LINQ to Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693052.aspx). It is equal to the following statement:

```
db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Autor).ToList().Where(t => t.Managers.Contains(currentUser)).ToList();
```

Note the additional `ToList()` after the `Include`. However, this may perform very poorly if you have a lot of tasks, since all your tasks are fetched from the database and only filtered afterwards.

You should try to use the approach shown by @FelipeOriani, since in that case only the relevant tasks are fetched from the database.